# Spring rabbitmq attaching new queue to existing listener

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I have a need to dynamically declare and assign new queues to my existing listener.

I have a listener declared like so:

```
@Component
public class AccountListener {
    @RabbitListener(id = "foobar")
    public String foo(String a) {
        System.out.println(a);
        return a + "xxx";
    }
}
```

I can retrieve this listener using `RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry`, but how do I expose it via a queue?

```
@Autowired
private AmqpAdmin rabbit;
@Autowired
private RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry registry;


public void exposeQueue(String queueName) throws Exception {
      Queue queue = new Queue(queueName, false);

      rabbit.declareQueue(queue);
      SimpleMessageListenerContainer listener = (SimpleMessageListenerContainer) registry.getListenerContainer("foobar");

     // Attach $listener to $queue here

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the queue to the container's list of queues:

```java
listener.addQueueNames(queueName);
```

[addQueueNames()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/listener/SimpleMessageListenerContainer.html#addQueueNames-java.lang.String...-) method will add the queue to the container at runtime. See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/htmlsingle/#listener-queues) for more info.

Comment: Adding a queue to the container doesn't register all the listeners to the queue.

Comment: @duffymo could you elaborate?

Comment: It worked for me on spring boot 2.0.3, but now I had to move to 2.1.0.M4 and the listener no longer responds to the queue, even though both queue and listener are registered in admin